# How to have a button open one scene and close the other (JavaFX)?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have two scenes for Donuts and Coffee. On a clicking on button_orderDonuts it should open the scene for Donuts but close the scene for Coffee. While clicking on button_orderCoffee it should open the scene for Coffee but close the scene for Donuts. How can I have a button to have two functionalities. Also, I'm using SceneBuilder.

```
    @FXML
    private Button button_orderCoffee;

    @FXML
    private Button button_orderDonuts;

    /**
    * Go to Coffee UI
    * @param event
    */
   @FXML
   void goToCoffee(ActionEvent event)
   {
       try
       {
           FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
           fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("CoffeeView.fxml"));
           Scene coffeeView = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 445, 464);
           Stage coffeeViewStage = new Stage();
           coffeeViewStage.setTitle("Order Coffee");
           coffeeViewStage.setScene(coffeeView);
           coffeeViewStage.show();

           CoffeeController coffeeController = fxmlLoader.getController();
           coffeeController.setMainController(this);

       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   /**
    * Go to Donut UI
    * @param event
    */
   @FXML
   void goToDonut(ActionEvent event)
   {
       try
       {
           FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
           fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("DonutView.fxml"));
           Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 445, 464);
           Stage stage = new Stage();
           stage.setTitle("Order Donut");
           stage.setScene(scene);
           stage.show();

           DonutController donutController = fxmlLoader.getController();
           donutController.setMainController(this);
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

Comment: Post a [mre]. There are multiple ways you could be linking these together, and the answer depends on how you’re doing so. A complete example is needed for an answer.

Comment: Assuming they are not linked and just 2 seperate scenes how should I do it? or Can you please give me some idea/method how I can close the scene upon opening of the other?

Comment: Both buttons and events are in the same class?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I create an example that you might be able to get some ideas from. https://github.com/sedj601/CoffeeDonutExample

Answer (score 0):

So considering that you only need to create a new scene once it is often best practice to just load the scenes once, make a stage, and then modify which scene is loaded into the stage. Something like this would be better in essence, though it is even better still to have a class which loads the scenes and then passes them to a view to handle switching. I see that you are trying to `getController()` and then set it. From my experience it is best to load the fxml without a controllew ant then set it before calling load. Like mentioned previously, I spent time doing this recently (like hours and hours) and got a very reliable MVC system working, feel free to ask more, I am happy to share (it took a while so better to share the knowledge heh)

That said here is a hopefully working example.

```
@FXML
private Button button_orderCoffee;

@FXML
private Button button_orderDonuts;

private Scene coffeeScene;
private Scene donutScene;

private Stage stage;


void loadScenes() {
    // Load coffee scene and set controller
    FXMLLoader coffeeLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CoffeeView.fxml"));
    coffeeLoader.setController(this)
    coffeeScene = new Scene(coffeeLoader.load());
     
    // Load donut scene and set controller
    FXMLLoader donutLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DonutView.fxml"));
    donutLoader.setController(this)
    donutScene = new Scene(donutLoader.load());
     
}



/**
* Go to Coffee UI
* @param event
*/
@FXML
void goToCoffee(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
      stage.setTitle("Order Coffee");
      stage.setScene(coffeeScene);
      sStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
* Go to Donut UI
* @param event
*/
@FXML
void goToDonut(ActionEvent event) {
   try {
       stage.setTitle("Order Donut");
       stage.setScene(donutScene);
       stage.show();
   } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

This way you call load scenes once and create a single stage, just changing which scene is set each time. Again you will need to make sure `fx:controller="..."` in the fxml files is removed. Do not make them empty, remove it entirely. On any buttons where a function is called, lets say on the `button_orderCoffee` where `onAction="#goToCoffee"` is called, this will appear red like an error. That is simply because it cannot see a controller, but since a controller is being set before the scene is loaded the actions will work on compile and run. This allows you to make a single instance of the controller and set it, allowing you to reference the controller and other classes.

The scene loading does not have to be in its own function, it can just be called on load depending how things are setup. If this is in the MVC style I recommend putting this code in the view or the initial setup and referencing the controller.

As @Kleopatra mentioned, it is better practice to use seperate controllers for each scene. I would advise using a model or some other class to mediate between the two if you need to share data amongst the two

Comment: beware: fxml and controller instances should be strictly 1:1 to avoid hard-to-debug errors (often NPEs)

Comment: @kleopatra what do you mean by that? A specific controller for each scene?

Comment: you load 2 different fxmls into the same controller instance (xx.setController(this)) - simply don't :) Instead, have two different controllers - each specific for the required ui - and load each with its specific fxml